# What (void(^)(NSString *)) as method parameter means in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, methods, block

I have to use some private API of my employer and i've got method like this:

```
- (void)login:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password delegate:(void(^)(NSString *))delegate;
```

What `(void(^)(NSString *))delegate` means?

This is parameter but i don't know what must be here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a block pointer.  If you are unfamiliar with blocks, this basically lets you assign an annonymous function inline as a parameter.  The signature here says that the block takes an NSString as a parameter, and returns nothing.  You would use it like this:

```
- (void)login:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password delegate:(void(^)(NSString *))delegate;

[someReceiver login:yourUsername password:yourPassword delegate:^(NSString *aString)
{
     // This is the block (annonymous function).  Do something with the aString paramter
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

It denotes a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) - it's essentially a closure (lambda function, whatever you call it) - Apple's addition to the C language. In this case, it returns `void` and accepts an `NSString` object as its only argument.